# How to know how each IP is utilised in a azure subnet?

Tags: azure

I want to create a new subnet and move all resources that are in old subnet. For that purpose I want to know which are the resources that is connected to a specific(old) subnet. How to do it. any idea is appreciated I am confused.

Answer (score 2):

I found out how to do it. We have to go into VNet and then connected devices in sidebar. It list all services connected to a subnet in that VNET.